# HTML srcset - when to use the x descriptor?

Tags: html, responsive-design, descriptor, srcset, responsive-images

I'm reading up on responsive images in HTML5 and have a question.

When would you use the x-descriptor? If for example you have different resolution versions of the same image why would you ever not use the w-descriptor?
As I understand it if you define:

```html
<img src="fallback.img" alt"txt"
     srcset="large.jpg 1024w,
             medium.jpg 640w,
             small.jpg  320w,"
     sizes="250px"   
     alt="txt">
```

Then the browser figures out the pixel densities anyway by dividing the width of the images (1024,640,320) - provided by the w-descriptor with the width that they are going to be displayed at (250) - provided by the sizes attribute. And by getting the pixel densities the browser can account for high density displays.

This is how I understand it so far, if I am wrong I would love to know it. So when is the w descriptor not the best option/when is the x descriptor preferable?

Comment: You understand it right. If you define just one `sizes` value in `px`, you mimic the feature of the x descriptor. The only reason to use the x descriptor in those cases would be: It is shorter syntax. Historically the x descriptor was before the w descriptor.

Answer (score 2):

Previously, I only used the `x` descriptor when the rendered size of the image was fixed, which happened really not that often.

The only advantage was that some browsers supported the `x` descriptor but to the `w` one.

Now that browsers support is widespread, I only use the `w` descriptor, and rarely `<picture>`.